# What is the appropriate LSTM model for multiclass text classification? Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, text-classification

I'm working in proyect to **predict personality type** from **Myers-Briggs** test. I would like to get an appropiate LSTM model for this multiclass text classification problem.

- **The labels**: there are **16 types** of personality
- **The dataset** have: **70,800 words**. Where was divided into 80% to training data and 20% to validation data.

---

**Size:**

- **Training data (X_train)**: 56,640 words.
- **Validation data (Y_val)**: 14,160 words.

```py
train_data_padded.size
validation_padded.size
```

---

**Padded**:

training and validation data are padded with **max lenght of 240**.

**E.g.:**

```py
training_padded = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(training_sequences,
                                                                  maxlen = 240,
                                                                  dtype = 'int32',
                                                                  padding = 'post',
                                                                  truncating = 'post',
                                                                  value = 0.0)
```

---

**SHAPE:**

```py
training padded: {train_data_padded.shape}
validation padded: {validation_padded.shape}

training padded: (236, 240)
validation padded: (59, 240)
```

---

**Expected output:**
There can be two types of output:

1. **1 output:** where is the type of personality with more accuracy.

```
INTJ: 0,84%
```

2. **16 outputs:** where it's given 16 types of personality showing each percentage of accuracy.

```
INTJ: 0,5 | INTP: 0,45 | ENTP: 0,8 | ... | ISFP: 0,20
```

---

**What I tried?:** I already tried some of the LSTM models from the TF website, however, I would like to know your own answer on this topic.

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(56640, 240),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(240)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(240, activation='relu'),
    # When we have multiple outputs, softmax convert outputs layers into a probability distribution.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='softmax')
    ])

#loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

---

*Before trying to close the question, please make any suggestion to improve it, will be considered.*

Comment: what is your problem? is the f1 score you get too low ? the keras code looks good at first sight. Have you tried simple scikit-learn models ? What f1 score do you get in comparison?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean with f1 score, when I use it I'm getting loss:nan, val: nan. I have other similar questions, but I'm not getting any improvement.